# How can I use 2 submit buttons in a single form in HTML & Django?

Tags: python, html, django

In this, only second button is working. If I delete the second button, then the first button is worked.I want to work both buttons.How can I work them?

HTML template
IInd_std.html

```
  <form method="get" action="#">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
    <th>Slno</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Attendance</th> 
        </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
        <td>Abijith</td>
        <td>{{ u }}
<input type="submit"  value="present" name="add20"/>
<input type="submit" value="absent" name="add21"/>
{{ v }}
    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

views.py

```
u = 1; v = 1
def IInd_std(request):
    global u,v

    my_dictionary = {
    "u" : u, "v" : v
    }
    if request.GET.get('add20'):
        u = u+1
        my_dictionary = {
            "u" : u,
        }
    if request.GET.get('add21'):
        v = v+1
        my_dictionary = {
            "v" : v,
        }


    return render(request, 'blog/IInd_std.html', my_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
request.GET['add20']:
```

and

```
request.GET['add21']:
```

Also, you are re-initializing `my_dictionary` in your if statements.

Change it to:

```
my_dictionary["u"] = u
```

and

```
my_dictionary["v"] = v
```